# RenderHook improperly wrapping context provider and causing Context to be undefined in testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a test that should render a hook via `renderHook`, and also wrap it in a context provider:

```js
describe("useShowMessages", () => {
  const amendedMockContext = {
    ...baseMockContext, // baseMockContext is jut an object I've been using with a value for each item I have in context.
    conversationData: {
      data: [{ key: "test" }],
    },
  };
  const MockContext = createContext(amendedMockContext);
  it("should return a full visibility tree on first call", () => {
    const wrapper = ({ children }: any) => (
      // @ts-ignore
      <MockContext.Provider value={amendedMockContext}>
        {children}
      </MockContext.Provider>
    );
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useShowMessages(), { wrapper });
    console.log(result.current);
  });
});
```

I use context in my hook like so:

```js
export const useShowMessages = () => {
  const {
    conversationData: { data },
    setNeedsInputIndexes,
    showChat,
    setCurrentStep,
  } = useContext(AppContext);

 // the rest of the hook logic
}
```

However, when I try to run this test, I always get the same error:

```sh
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

       5 | export const useShowMessages = () => {
       6 |   const {
    >  7 |     conversationData: { data },
         |                         ^
       8 |     setNeedsInputIndexes,
       9 |     showChat,
      10 |     setCurrentStep,
```

You can see that the test is failing where I am trying to extract context values using `useContext`. It is not recognising `data` at all.

I've set it up following the examples laid out in [testing-library docs](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/advanced-hooks) as well as the examples in [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/test-custom-hooks-using-react-hooks-testing-library-a3a37031a9be). I have other tests using context and `baseMockContext`/`amendedMockContext`, as well as other `renderHook` tests. they all work fine, but this is my first that uses both in conjunction and it doesn't work...

EDIT:

Here's my AppContext for use in the actual application:

```
import { createContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";
import {
  ConversationDataType,
  FetchResultsType,
  IntroductionDataType,
} from "./types";

export type AppContextType = {
  // a bunch of types
};

export const AppContext = createContext({} as AppContextType);
```

Comment: In the test you are using `MockContext` and in the hook you are using `AppContext`. That doesn't look right - where does `AppContext` come from?

Comment: @BenWainwright added appcontext. It starts life as just an empty object.

Comment: Yeah but in the implementation you are not using that. You need to pass in the same reference that creates the provider for context to work

Comment: @BenWainwright Changing the context creation call to `createContext({} as AppContextType)` still causes the same error.

Comment: Well it will do - that has literally no runtime effect. But you appear to be using different references. Ie a different context variable in the test and in the implementation

Comment: @BenWainwright Could you please explain what you mean a little bit more? Yes in my test I instantiated my context with a full rather than an empty object, but the context was replaced by the `amendedMockContext` - which looks just like the series of `useState` variables I set up in my actual app that then gets passed to `value`. I'm not sure why that would prevent me from runnign the test, as by the time the test is run that `value` is already set to be `amendedMockContext`. `amendedMockContext` includes `data` because of the `wrapper`, so should not be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, but you are creating a *different* context in your test by calling *createContext* again. The provider you are using in your tests is for *that* context, not your AppContext, so I wouldn't expect that to work. What you probably need to do is create a provider in the file that creates the context, and then import that into your tests

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am amazed that there is no pattern / helper for passing test state through, having so many issues with this. Have a render helper created for my app, but renderHook doesn't want to behave the same and accept a state.